# Choose keyboard input for background program in C and ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, input, keyboard

I have my main program in C and WxWidgets, which runs in the foreground on ubuntu at startup, and it reads input from a USB magnetic card reader that works like a  emulated keyboard.

I need to have another program, which runs in the background, and takes input only from a second magnetic card reader connected to another USB port.

The problem is that I do not specify any USB port in the code, because they work like keyboards, so I just have to capture the character flow.

Is there any way to make the background program accept characters from the second reader only?

I tried on Google but I found nothing. Is it possible to do that in `C` or `C++`?

Comment: Why does card reader work as an emulated keyboard?

Comment: I do not know, all the magnetic card readers work like an emulated keyboard. You set the mouse cursor wherever you want, you swipe, and the string appears.

Comment: For my application, I have a text control box with focus on, so the cursor is already in the box during the card swiping.

Comment: No tips? I wasn't able to find a good solution. Is there a way to detect the input flow which comes from a specific device?